# Compare data frame column values in datetime with integer?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe column with dates (already converted into datetime format). Now I need to compare the years in the column with a number, for example:

```
Date 
01-02-2018
04-07-2016
09-09-2019
```

and I want to make this comparison:

```
if dfA['Date'].dt.year == current:
   ## do something
```

There are two problems:

The code gives me this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

and the number is from a user input assigned to the name current (I convert current to int using the following code):

```
current = int(args.User_Input)
```

Not sure why it is giving me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want your if-clause to evaluate to `True` if any of the years in `dfA['Date']` is equal to `current`?
If so, you can do as follows:

```
if dfA['Date'].dt.year.eq(current).sum():
   # do something
```

Comment: what if I want to say smaller?

Comment: @BrunnaT. then you can do `if dfA['Date'].dt.year.le(current+1).sum():`. It will evaluate to true if any year is smaller than `current`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Creating the data you specified
times = ['01-02-2018',
        '04-07-2016',
        '09-09-2019']

#converting to a dataframe
dfA = pd.DataFrame(times)

#Renaming the dataframe to the correct name
dfA.rename(columns={0:'Date'},inplace=True)

#formatting
dfA['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfA['Date'], format='%m-%d-%Y')

#User input. Must be an int
currentYear = int(input('Enter Year:'))

#Need to specify the index number using .values[n] to specify which year you're testing against
if dfA['Date'].dt.year.values[0] == currentYear:
    print('Do Something')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because the statement `dfA['Date'].dt.year == current` is a pandas.Series of Booleans, not a single Boolean value:

```
dfA['Date'].dt.year == 2018
# 0     True
# 1    False
# 2    False
# Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

The python `if` statement doesn't know what to do with this:  should the block of code under the `if` statement run because *any* of the values in this Series is true?  Or should it not run because *not all* of the values are true?  Or should it run because the Series itself is not a falsey value, like `None` or zero?  The intent is ambiguous, hence the error.

If you want to perform some operation on the DataFrame for all the columns that meet the criterion you specify, consider using [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).  That Series that you make can be used to select certain rows of the DataFrame, like so:

```
dfA['example'] = 100
is_matching_year = dfA['Date'].dt.year == 2018
dfA.loc[is_matching_year, 'example'] *= 2
print(dfA[['Date', 'example']])
#         Date  example
# 0 2018-01-02      200
# 1 2016-04-07      100
# 2 2019-09-09      100
```